# How can I expose my Laravel API in index.php?

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, production

I'm putting an app into production in Laravel for the first time. I know that `index.php` is the entry point to a Laravel app, but my app has no front end. It is an API with a list of routes in `routes/api.php`. How can I expose this to `index.php` (and my hosting provider)?

Comment: Point your servers webroot to Laravels `/public` folder.

Comment: @commonsense Thank you!

Comment: Laravel has pretty good documentation, I suggest you read it